# Can a job offer be rescinded for speeding citation?

Tags: united-states, background-check

Late last year I got a speeding citation for going 15 over the speed limit and I recently landed a job offer in consulting and one of the things that is required is a background check.

Sure enough the HR department found out about the speeding violation I had for going over 15 mph. It came out as "Pending" in their criminal background check. Since the courts have been backed up due to Covid, my court date has been delayed until June of this year. So there is no resolution regarding this violation.

I explained this to the HR department. Could my job offer be pulled because of something like this?

Comment: 15 over the speed limit? Is that really a speeding violation? In my state, which is California, 15 over the speeding limit is considered "reckless driving". Anyway, is online driving school an option for that ticket? If you can save some of the points on your license with driving school that may assuage your new employer. Were they planning to give you a company car?

Comment: What state are you located in? Usually, the background-checking laws will vary from state to state.

Comment: North Carolina. It's showed up as "Speeding" here on my record in the background check.

Comment: It is an “offer” not a contract signed sealed and delivered. Which is why it is only an offer, it can be rescinded by them or refused by you.

Answer (score 9):

> Could my job offer be pulled because of something like this?

Yes it could. But it probably won't derail a job offer for a consulting position.

Since there's nothing you can do about it at this point anyway, try not to worry. Just wait for the decision.

Answer (score 5):

A job offer “can” be pulled for any reason that is not against the law in your locality, especially if there is not a signed employment contract.

Will they?  Depends.  If the job is driving then I’d be concerned, for an office job it’s super unlikely (how would they hire anyone if even traffic citations were a blocker)?

However, without a location and industry this is unanswerable.

Comment: I freaked out when the HR person reached out to me about the citation. I was shocked this would show up but it sure did. Wow this world is cruel.

Comment: Did you ask *them* if it was an impediment?

Comment: I did but I didn't get a clear answer from the person I spoke too. It seems like someone else above her gets to decide.

Comment: Well then clearly it could be - worrying won’t help anything though.

Answer (score 2):

The are multiple items that can be done during a background check:

- Financial
- Job History
- Education
- Criminal
- Driving

The items included in the check is either linked to the specific job or the same ones are done by the company regardless of the potion within the company.

The company should have given you paperwork explaining the scope of the checks. You may have had to sign a form giving them permission.

Many times the company give you the opportunity to tell them about issues before they do the background check. Telling them in advance can make them less damaging because you weren't hiding them.

The decision about does X disqualify Y is a decision only they can make. The offer you have is one with at least one condition. That means they can rescind the offer if they don't like the results.

The reason why the advice is not to quit while there are still conditions is because a background check can take an unknown amount of time, and you can still be rejected.